# set cookies on external site for used in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i used wordpress external-database-authentication plugin for external db connect user athentication . if user login in my external site after he came to my wordpress blog  then he is loged in wordpress blog. i used below function this function is working well in my localhost but in server its not working.  whats the problem with it ?

```
$check = 'auth';
include('../news/wp-config.php'); 
include(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php');
wp_setcookie($email, $user_pass, false, '', '', $check);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Keep in mind that cookies are defined for a specific domain, so maybe cookies are inaccessible on one page.

Comment: yes cookies are not generating on server  i test it. so in wordpress page senerio what will be soloution of this function

Answer (score 0):

Try using the root cookie plugin in wordpress. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/root-cookie/